Im confused as to how the calculations in finding a most powerful test and a UMP differs
I know that for a simple hypothesis to get a MP, You take the ratio of likelihoods by the NP lemma but I'm not sure as to how this extends to UMP and how the calculations would differ

Perhaps you first begin to understand the difference between two.
